# Getting 0 results when I should not be

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am running this query

```
select * 
from PortalUser 
where ID not in (select distinct PortalUserID from LoginHistory where LoginDateTime > '10/1/2012')
```

and getting 0 results.

If I run

```
select distinct PortalUserID 
from LoginHistory 
where LoginDateTime > '10/1/2012'
```

I get a result set as expected. Lets say 50 results

If I run

```
select * 
from portalUser
```

I get 200 Results.

Why is this?

Just to be clear. The LoginHistory table has a PortalUserID that does not have to be Unique, however the PortalUser..ID is a unique field.

Running this query

```
select count(ID) 
from PortalUser 
GO
select count(Distinct PortalUserID) 
from LoginHistory where LoginDateTime > '10/1/2012''
```

returns 119 and 47 rows

Comment: Your results are strongly suggesting that everyone listed in PortalUser has a LoginDateTime > 10/1/2012 . You could verify that by doing `select count(*) from PortalUser` and comparing it against `select distinct PortalUserID from LoginHistory where LoginDateTime > '10/1/2012'

Comment: I know for a fact that I have users that have not logged in in the last 2 months. This is a development environment and one of the users was a developer that resigned 2 years ago. His last login date was sometime in early 2011

Comment: Try using NOT EXISTS rather than NOT IN. It's a better pattern anyway, but if PortalUserID is nullable, it could be throwing off results. Also stop using unsafe and ambiguous datetime formats. What if that's being interpreted as Jan 10 instead of Oct 1? Use YYYYMMDD for date-only string literals. I doubt it will fix this specific problem, but it is a much better practice.

Comment: I'd also suggest throwing table schema and sample data that reproduces the problem up on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: I got it figured out. Aaron Bertrand had it right. It just wasnt clicking with me with what everyone was saying. I had a Null value in the LoginHistory..portalUser field. I deleted that and I got a valid result set. I would think that SQL should throw and error if it cant complete something like this but that may just be me.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: No, SQL Server should not throw an error. Equality checks with NULLs yield unknown (which essentially means false) - you need to understand NULLs and how both the SQL standard and your RDBMS of choice treats them.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is only selecting `ID` **NOT** in the `PortalUserID` list returned by your sub-query.  Are there records in PortalUser that do not have the IDs returned from your sub-query.

Comment: Yes, our PortalUser table has an ID which looks like this PortalUser..ID = LoginHistory..LoginID